# "Anything" in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> Do you know anything about my next appointment time?

How to ask that question in German, especially *anything* in this case (question form). How to say it?

So, the sentences I need to translate into German (to notice the difference) are:

- *A: It doesn't matter, I'll accept anything he will say.*
- *B: Do you know anything about my next appointment time?*
- *C: Anything you want, whatever, I'll bring it to you.*

Can you please translate those 3 phrases.

Comment: Feels like a translation request based on "I need to translate [...] Can you please translate". In general there are two translations that fit to "anything" quite often: "alles" and "(irgend)etwas": Ich akzeptiere alles; Weißt du irgendwas; Alles was du willst. The only question is: Does "anything" equal any thing at all (->alles) or "something" in negative sentences and questions(->irgendwas). And "not anything" is than of course the opposite, i.e. "nichts".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A:

> It doesn't matter, I'll accept anything he will say.
>   Das macht nichts, ich werde **alles** akzeptieren, was er sagt.
>   Das macht nichts, ich werde **alles**, was er sagt, akzeptieren.

B:

> Do you know anything about my next appointment time?
>   Weißt du **etwas** über meinen nächsten Termin?

C:

> Anything you want, whatever, I'll bring it to you.
>   1: Egal was du willst, ich werde es dir bringen.
>   2: Ich bringe dir **alles** was du (haben) willst.

About C:
In Version 1 I did translate »whatever« (»egal«), but in this case you don't have a word in the German sentence, that matches with »anything«.
In Version 2 I translated »anything« (»alles«), but then there is no good possibility to insert a translation of »whatever« in the German sentence. (»Haben« is optional in this case.)
If you really want to have a translation of both words in one German sentence, then you end up with something like this:

> 3: Ich bringe dir **alles** *was* du (haben) willst, egal *was* es ist.

There are variations of this sentence with different word order. But the problem is, that now you have two times the word »was« in the sentence, which is no good style. And you can leave off either »was du (haben) willst« or »egal was es ist« to improve style without changing the meaning much.

Here are some other examples for translating *anything*:

- > You can tell me anything.
  >   Du kannst mir **alles** sagen.
- > There is hardly anything that can help me.
  >   Es gibt kaum **etwas**, das mir helfen kann.
- > You don't need to pay anything here.
  >   Du musst hier **nichts** bezahlen. / Sie müssen hier **nichts** bezahlen.
- > Is there **anything** of importance?
  >   Gibt es **irgendetwas** von Bedeutung?
- > This does not change **anything**.
  >   Das ändert **gar nichts**.

Comment: You might add a version 3 for C that covers the "whatever" part: "Ich bringe Dir, was auch immer Du haben willst".